# Turn every line of txt into list with strings

Tags: python, string, file, txt, file-processing

how to turn each line of txt file  into list of strings

example  sentences

```
board games for kids
house with view on the sea
```

I need output like this in python

```
sentences = ["board games for kids ","house  with view on the sea"]
```

Comment: Where are you getting the strings from?

Comment: Each line of a text file are already a list of strings

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for the "needs debugging details" reason. This is a trivial file i/o task you should be able to attempt after reading a bare minimum of documentation and related questions. For this reason we expect you to share your attempt, not just a code writing request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    sentences = list(f)
```

Or if you don't want the `\n` at the end just do

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    sentences = [line[:-1] for line in f]
```

Comment: this assumes the last line ends with a newline character

Answer (score 0):

lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('file.txt')]